# Order of subgroup of a group with order product of two coprime numbers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

While reading a proof, I encountered this argument:

Let $G$  be a group of order $|G|=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $|H|=a'b'$, where $a'\mid a$ and $b'\mid b$, and $b'<b$. Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $|A|=a$.

What I do not understand is the following statement: since $AH$ is a subgroup of $G$, using Lagrange's theorem we have that, $|AH|=\alpha \beta$, where $\alpha \mid a$ and $\beta \mid b$.

I know that the order of $AH$ is $|AH|=\frac{|A||H|}{|A\cap H|}=\frac{aa'b'}{|A\cap H|}$. But I do not know how to conclude from here that the order is $|AH|=\alpha \beta$, with $\alpha \mid a$ and $\beta \mid b$.

Any hints as to how to prove this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what text did you read this proof?

Comment: For **any** positive integer $n=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, **every** divisor $d$ of $n$ can be written as $d=\alpha\beta$ with $\alpha|a$ and $\beta|b$. It has nothing to do with groups, or the order of $AH$. This is just basic elementary number theory. Just take $\alpha=\gcd(d,a)$, $\beta=\gcd(d,b)$ and use the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score -1):

Lagrange's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

Gives $|G|=[G:A]\cdot |A|$. In particular, you know $|A|=a$, so $[G:A]=b$, which says that $A$ is 'maximal' in the sense that it is not contained in any larger subgroup of $G$ whose order is coprime to $b$. Now consider the group $AH$. We know that $|AH|\geq |A|$ and $|AH|\geq |H|$. The first gives us immediately that $a$ divides $|AH|$, as it must contain every element of $A$ which is of order $a$, so we know that $\alpha =a$. Now because $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $b'$ divides $b$ we have that $a$ and $b'$ are coprime. Hence $|A\cap H|$ is a divisor of $a$, which tells us that the elements of $H$ responsible for the factor $b'$ in $|H|$ have trivial intersection with $A$. Therefore we can actually conclude that $b'$ divides $|AH|$, which implies $\beta = b'$. Now we have $|AH|=\alpha \beta$ with $\alpha \mid a$ and $\beta \mid b$.